# How to find an equation for $x$ in terms of $t$ for a particle falling under gravity with resistance given by $mkv^2$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, drag, integration

Okay so I have determine the velocity $v$ and displacement $x$ as functions of $t$  for a particle falling under gravity with resistance given by $mkv^2$.

I have set up the equation of motion divided by $c$ and integrated (it was a tricky integral) to give the following result.

$$v(t)=\frac{\sqrt{(g/k)}(e^{2t\sqrt{g/k}}-1)}{1+e^{2t\sqrt{g/k}}}$$ so $$\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{\sqrt{(g/k)}(e^{2t\sqrt{g/k}}-1)}{1+e^{2t\sqrt{g/k}}}$$ and $$x(t)=\int\frac{\sqrt{(g/k)}(e^{2t\sqrt{g/k}}-1)}{1+e^{2t\sqrt{g/k}}}~dt+C$$ but I can't do this to be honest.

Any help?

Comment: Can you use integral tables? Your v(t) function is a hyperbolic tangent. Also double check the argument of the exponentials.

Comment: Is there an error in this forumla arrrrrrghhhhhhhhhhhhhh

Comment: tey, accepting an answer means being nice to people that have tried to help you: you just click on the $V$ _chevron_ under the number of votes, and it becomes green. If you have any doubts click on _help_ button on the right. If one sees that a member does not usually accept answer is discouraged to give you an answer

Answer (score 1):

Disregarding the constants, you have an integral in the form

$$
I = \int \frac{e^t - 1}{e^t + 1}dt.
$$

Now, it might be clear to apply various methods at that point. I choose to make the following:

$$
I  = \int \frac{e^{t/2}(e^{t/2}-e^{-t/2})}{e^{t/2}(e^{t/2}+e^{t/2})}dt.
$$

By eliminating the $e^{t/2}$ factors and recognizing the terms in the parantheses as [hyperbolic functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_function) you should be able to get

$$
I = \int \frac{\sinh (t/2)}{\cosh (t/2)} dt
$$

which is now easy to solve by substituting $u = \cosh (t/2)$ and realizing that the numerator is just the derivative of $u$ with a multiplicative factor of $2$. Hence you have

$$
I = \frac{1}{2} \ln|\cosh(t/2)| + c.
$$

Now, you can safely apply the same procedure to your problem with the given constants.